# Problem connecting to Oracle server using SSL and ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, ssl, odp.net

I can't connect to Oracle using SSL from ODP.Net.

I verified all configurations, I remake the wallets and certificates, exchanged certificates… but nothing works.

From SQLPlus the SSL connections are opening correctly, same using Toad, but impossible from .Net which I'm getting this inner exception:

```
Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted
```

The application uses .net Framework 4.7.2. In our development environment the SSL connection doesn't work. The same application in our production environment is working properly. So for me is a configuration problem in my development machine related with .net and C#, but I'm not able to find the cause. We made some days ago a clean installation of the Oracle Client 19c (19.3.0) and I'm not sure if there are other configuration files that could be modified (regarding my old installation).

I'm using this light test code:

```cs
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Data Source=dsssl")
conn.TnsAdmin = @"C:\app\oracle\product\19.3.0\client_64\network\admin";
conn.Open();
```

I tried also to set the ‘WalletLocation’ but it doesn't change anything. It finds correctly the wallet using the tsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure you load the correct ODP.NET driver? Have a look at [Installation Does Not Register Oracle Data Provider for .Net in the GAC.](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2272241_1.html)

Comment: I am using a Nuget package instead of the Oracle client ODP.NET dll. Nevertheless I tried to install the ODP.NET assemblies in the GAC but nothing changed, I still get this underlaying error.